# Why does dynamically creating a Layout be different from creating it in xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, orientation

This is my xml created file for a layout and it displays as I want it to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageSectionCustomRowL"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/titleCustomRowL"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#959595"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/subTitleCustomRowL"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is more or less the same thing but created dynamically via code

```
LinearLayout parentLL = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.newsMainPopulationLL);
    LinearLayout parentRowLL = new LinearLayout(news.this);
    parentRowLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    Drawable bg = news.this.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.dialog_holo_light_frame);
    //Drawable bbg = getDrawable(android.R.drawable.dialog_holo_light_frame);
    parentRowLL.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.dialog_holo_light_frame);
    parentRowLL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, convertDpToPx(120)));
    LinearLayout parentRowChildHLL = new LinearLayout(news.this);
    parentRowChildHLL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    parentRowChildHLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout containerForPic = new LinearLayout(news.this);
    containerForPic.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(convertDpToPx(75), convertDpToPx(75)));
    containerForPic.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ImageView picInList = new ImageView(news.this);
    picInList.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    LinearLayout contentVerticalLL = new LinearLayout(news.this);
    contentVerticalLL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    contentVerticalLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    TextView headingTV = new TextView(news.this);
    headingTV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    headingTV.setPadding(convertDpToPx(10), convertDpToPx(10), convertDpToPx(10), 0);
    headingTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    headingTV.setTextSize(30);
    TextView contentTV = new TextView(news.this);
    contentTV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    contentTV.setPadding(convertDpToPx(10), convertDpToPx(5), convertDpToPx(10), convertDpToPx(10));
    contentTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#959595"));
    contentVerticalLL.addView(headingTV);
    contentVerticalLL.addView(contentTV);
    parentRowChildHLL.addView(contentVerticalLL);
    containerForPic.addView(picInList);
    parentRowChildHLL.addView(containerForPic);
    parentRowLL.addView(parentRowChildHLL);
    parentLL.addView(parentRowLL);
```

Here convertDptoPx is a int() that works properly. However for some reason the Linear layout parentRowChildLL even though set to `LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL` for orientation for some reason displays vertically (According to the layout boundaries I see using the developer options setting)

Is there something basic I'm missing out yet? When I see the boundaries I have 3 rows. And also I tried encasing my image view in the layout because otherwise it is not even visible.

Thank You.

Comment: Where is 'newsMainPopulationLL'? Also, what's the intent of this execution – as I'm confident there are better ways to accomplish it than to programmatically build your UI.

Comment: @EvanBashir newsMainPopulationLl is the main view where I won't to add several Row views. I don't want to use list view either.

Comment: Can't help you if we can't see the code, or understand the intent.

Comment: @EvanBashir I have posted the code. As for the intent. I have a particular layout, much like a custom list row Layout. However instead of using it as a list row layout I want to run it inside a for loop so it creates a bunch of custom rows with the 2 text views and 1 image view. Doing this in xml I got the desired effect I wanted but in code it looks different.

Comment: Nothing with the id `newsMainPopulationLL`, is listed in the XML above. As for your list, it ideally should be implemented using a `ListView` following the adapter pattern seen here: [Android ListView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

Comment: I havnt added the Id's yet. This was just a small mockup I guess I should call it. I know I should be using a list view but for a few design reasons I don't want to use the list view.

Comment: I'd be curious to know those design reasons. If you haven't added the id's, why do you expect it to work? A lot of unknowns here, please revise your question if you'd like help.

Comment: @EvanBashir I will add the Id's soon. I haven't even added the loop yet. I just wanted to see first if the layouts design was proper or not. As for the design reasons I may want to adjust size of text, add dynamic images, give it the Holo light frame background etc. I believe this might be still achievable with a list view but I thought this method might be much easier

Comment: However still the main question remains unanswered why does the xml created and Java layout differ when the only change so far made was the removal of Id's, which are not exactly related to design